# How to make sure the height doesn't exceed the parent's height while also maintaining image's aspect ratio

Tags: css, calculation, aspect-ratio

I have an image which width should be as large as possible and I want it's height to not exceed the height of the parent while also maintaining the aspect ratio of 16:9. The issue right now is, it works well till the screen size is 1591px, if it gets bigger than that, the height exceeds and the vertical scroll bar appears. I don't want that behavior. How can I achieve that?

Comment: So do you want the image's height to be the maximum possible but not more than 100vh? Perhaps you could show us a code snippet where you set the height of the parent. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I have given it's parent's height to 70vh. My desire is to make sure users don't see the vertical scroll bar. In order to do that, I believe, the height of the image must not exceed the height of the parent(70vh).  But, the height is calculated dynamically base on the width. So, to limit the height, I guess we have to limit the width. How will I be able to achieve that??

Comment: `calc()` may be able to help in some way. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc

Answer (score 0):

the scrollBar appears because of the overflow you can do 2 things

1. use the "overflow: hidden;"

```
body{
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

2. you can use max-width to determine the max-width of the element and set it on both of the elements

I hope it was helpful

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**: the original answer assumed from the question that the image was an HTML img. The solution was to set width to 100% [of its container] and height to 70vh and use object-fit.

However, it is not an img it is a canvas.

The required aspect ratio is known to be 16 / 9. This snippet therefore sets the max-width to 100% (of whatever is the container) and the max-height to 70vh.

This way there can never be any overflow and the canvas will be as big as it can be within those constraints.

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  margin: 0;
}

canvas {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 70vh;
  aspect-ratio: 16 / 9;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<canvas width="1600" height="900"></canvas>
```

Comment: But, its not html image. So there is no object-fit contain available. I will have to calculate the height and width manually. Any idea?

Comment: Sorry I'm lost. If it's not an HTML img what is it? Could you put the relevant HTML into your question so we can see how you are rendering it?

Comment: It's actually an image inside canvas. I believe I can't give it any css style like object-fit: contain. Correct me if I am wrong. I will try to make a demo. Essentially, I need to maintain the aspect ratio of the image while making sure vertical scroll bar doesn't appear.

Comment: Well the use of canvas was totally unclear from your question - it shows the importance of adding the HTML structure to your question. And show how the canvas initial sizing is decided.

Comment: I think, we can just think of it like a div. I can give it height and width, but not other css properties. So, if the height of the canvas img reaches the parent's maximum height, I think I can just stop increasing the width. Since the height only gets enlarged as the width increases. But, I am not sure how to calculate yet. I thought mentioning Canvas was just unnecessary. Sorry for the confusions.